# How to share (cocoa)pods only(!) between iOS projects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

We started using CocoaPods in our iOS projects. By default we add a `Podfile` in a directory of our `.xcodeproj` file, call there `pod install` and CocoaPods generates a directory `${PODS_ROOT}/Pods` locally. Since we are adding Pods to the repo and the `${PODS_ROOT}/Pods` is quite large, we would like to move all shareable parts to some different place to be shared among projects. Is this possible?

Inside the `${PODS_ROOT}/Pods` for a project `A` I think that the files `Manifest.lock` and `A.xcodeproj` and the directory `Target Support Files` are specific to the project `A`. The rest of the directories are pods (containing frameworks or static libs or...) which could be shared. What would be the best / suggested way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to add any files in the ${PODS_ROOT} to your repo. Just add the Podfile and Podfile.lock and then let every developer run `pod install` when they need to install or update which Pods are used.

If you are developing your own Pods and want to share them between projects you can specify these in the Podfile as well.

Comment: Exactly. There is absolutely no need to put dependencies into repository. They have their own repositories on github.

Comment: You shouldn't add the `Podfile.lock` in the repo, otherwise there will be the possibility the `pod install` won't work

Comment: Not sure I agree, you should add it if you want to make sure that everyone is on the same version of Pods.

Comment: Well, if that is the way to go... I think that it could be better (in order to ensure that the right versions of the Pods are used) to have all the Pods in the repo, too. I also think that Erik is right regarding `Podfile.lock` which should be kept in the repo (as suggested on cocoapods.org) since there the versions of the installed Pods are stored. Anyway... I think we'll go that way and remove the Pods from the repo. Thanks.